# How to live stream video in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I want to live stream video from  web url in the format m3u8.So is there any way to play in blackberry os7.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to implement server side playlists for that. You can check out Wowza http://wowza.com/ or Helix servers http://www.realnetworks.com/helix/streaming-media-server/.